# Why does this code work only with *args in something()?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, arguments

Would someone mind taking a minute to explain why this code works when I give something() the parameter *args?  It seems as though it should work without it because something is being called without any arguments...  Stumped..

```
from Tkinter import *

mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('570x130+700+200')
mGui.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)
mGui.title('Title')

def something(*args):
        if someValue.get() == 'tom':
            mLabel2.lift()
        else:
            mLabel2.lower()

mylist = ['henry', 'tom', 'phil']
someValue = StringVar()
someValue.trace('w', something)

mLabel = Label(text = '  name:')
mLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)
mLabel2 = Label(text = 'Success')
mLabel2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)
mLabel2.lower()

someMenu = OptionMenu(mGui, someValue, *mylist)
someMenu.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
someMenu.config(width = 14, anchor = W)

mGui.mainloop()
```

**Edit, The program will initialize, but as soon as I select a value from someMenu it throws out TypeError: something() takes no arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function to the `trace` is called with 3 argument: `name1`, `name2`, `op` according to [Tcl `trace` documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/trace.htm#M14).

So the callback function should be following form:

```
def callback(name1, name2, op):
    pass
```

But, in question code, `something` does not use any of the parameters. So the function use [abitrary argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) (`*args`) to implicitly ignore them.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!